# What is this 2x4 brick with a clear bottom, a small hole at each end and a 6 brick high pole?

Tags: part-identification

[image: http://imgur.com/jqB16IE]

[image]

It is a 2x4 with a clear bottom a small hole at each end and it is smooth on top with a 6 high pole coming out.

The brick has no numbers on it so I'm not sure what it is I have tried searching for it however I can't find it if anyone knows what set this is from that would be great.

Comment: Are you sure it's LEGO? The green bricks in the background don't look like they are LEGO.

Comment: @Ambo100 Yes I am sorting a big box and separating the Lego from the non Lego the stuff in the background is some non lego

Comment: You mentioned you couldn't find a number, can you find the LEGO logo on the piece anywhere?

Comment: & other picture wrong, item of 2 part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's [799c800](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemPic.asp?P=799c800):

[image: 799c800]

This part was used to implement a simple "hand of god" steering system on a bunch of sets in the 70s.

[image: in action]

Comment: Image is up-side-down.

Comment: @AndrewHodson No, it's not: http://www.peeron.com/scans/336-1/5

Comment: Also wrong way up on peeron, was also on 1 other website which I've told the error. If you look at image Nos. you see 6 instead of 9.

Comment: @AndrewHodson Oh, sorry - you're indeed right: the previous image has steps 7-8 and the following one 10. Thanks for the heads-up! (Corrected it here)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Steering column complete, fire engine, tipping lorry, low loader that came with crane, also on its own 'Lego spares' at Wrexham. Look for 4 & 5 wide plate with a hole, plate with part 2 studs wide with hole, 4-stud wheels (or 1 stud & spokes) & a 1×2 with the word 'LEGO' on side.
1 of mine broken, = on fire engine. So I'm after 1.